"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error in minikube docker
I am using WSL, and there
I am running Kubernetes cluster inside minikube which is running on docker. When I am trying to create a pod, it always shows below error -
Failed to pull image "<image>": Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Though, When I am directly pulling images using docker command, it is working fine.

Are you trying to access a private registry?  Does your network environment have some sort of man-in-the-middle proxy that intercepts TLS connections?

No, I am pulling images from public registry.
Regarding the proxy, I think, there is because I am running on my company's PC.

It is related to the root certificates, There may be an issue with the Zscaler policy applied. If you are using a Linux machine run the below command to list the root certificates currently installed on your machine.
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh (chances are you won’t see the one for Zscaler).
Download Zscaler’s root cert in der format and convert it to pem (but make sure the extension is .crt. Otherwise it won’t work)
Copy the crt file to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
Once again run this command sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
It will read the crt file and add it to the available root cert store on your machine, try docker pull again. If all of your ca certificates were missing from /usr/share/ca-certificates/*
re-install the package and update-ca-certificates -f, do apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates.
EDIT-1
Network issue : WSL environments can sometimes have limited network connectivity, this may cause the Docker client inside Minikube to have difficulty reaching the registry. Also make sure the WSL firewall is not blocking outbound connections to the Docker registry.
Using latest docker image: First check the current Docker image version and Pull the latest Docker image and then stop and remove any running containers. At last create and run containers with the updated image. Refer to Goodness Chris-Ugari’s cherryservers Blog on How to Update a Docker Image | Step-by-Step Guide for more details.

As I told above, when I am doing docker pull it is working, problem is coming when same image is being used by a pod.

Based on your further inputs, I have updated my answer in EDIT-1 Section.  It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

So, I am running docker and minikube from WSL. Here docker is working fine, it is able to pull the images, run the containers, but in minikube when pod is trying to pull the same image it is throwing above error. And you point Using latest docker image does not look relevant to my question.

check this similar Github link ,which may help to resolve your issue.
